# SQL Server Exam

Tags: sql-server

I am studying for the SQL Server Exam one test question is:

> *The `SpatialLocation` column in the `Person.Address` table of the `AdventureWorks2012` database uses the geography data type. You want to create a query that outputs the `AddressID` column with the contents of the `SpatialLocation` column as coordinates in longitude and latitude format.*

And the answer:

```
SELECT AddressID, CAST(SpatialLocation as VARCHAR(45)) as "LON/LAT" from Person.Address
SELECT AddressID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(45), SpatialLocation) as "LON/LAT" from Person.Address
```

Just playing with code why wont the following work??

```
TRY_PARSE( SpatialLocation AS VARCHAR(45)) as "LON/LAT3"
```

I get:

> *Invalid data type varchar in function `TRY_PARSE`*

Comment: Seems to me this is difficult to answer if someone doesn't have the `AdventureWorks` database.

Comment: @njk - Not really. It is documented here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx. `varchar` is not one of the datatypes supported by `TRY_PARSE`

Comment: thanks for the speedy reply...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SpatialLocation has a `Geography` data type but `TRY_PARSE` takes a `nvarchar`.

```
TRY_PARSE ( string_value AS data_type )
```

Take a look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx

Good luck.

Comment: `SELECT TRY_PARSE( 'Foo' AS VARCHAR(45))` would still give the same error